# Why does String.split need pipe delimiter to be escaped?

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to parse a file that has each line with pipe delimited values.
It did not work correctly when I did not escape the pipe delimiter in split method, but it worked correctly after I escaped the pipe as below.

```
private ArrayList<String> parseLine(String line) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] list_str = line.split("\\|"); // note the escape "\\" here
    System.out.println(list_str.length);
    System.out.println(line);
    for(String s:list_str) {
        list.add(s);
        System.out.print(s+ "|");
    }
    return list;
}
```

Can someone please explain why the pipe character needs to be escaped for the `split()` method?

Comment: The answers below answered the "why," but just FYI, if you're trying to match a literal String you might also look at [Pattern.quote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)). It takes a `String` and returns a regex `String` that will match the input (ie, it takes care of all the escaping for you).

Comment: +1 for `Pattern.quote`

Answer (score 175, accepted):

`String.split` expects a regular expression argument.  An unescaped `|` is parsed as a regex meaning "empty string or empty string," which isn't what you mean.

Answer (score 76):

Because the syntax for that parameter to [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) is a regular expression, where in the `'|'` has a special meaning of OR, and a `'\|'` means a literal `'|'` so the string `"\\|"` means the regular expression `'\|'` which means match exactly the character `'|'`.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I almost always forget to use the double escape. Now that I know why it's that way, it will surely help me remember from now on.

Comment: What happens if the value of the String line has some Pipe characters? How would you be able to split without splitting escaped pipe  \| ?

Comment: @AlexandreJ Are you asking how to split a line that looks like: `Some|Delimited|Text|With|An\|Embedded|Pipe|Char` into `("Some", "Delimited", "Text", "With", "An\|Embedded", "Pipe", "Char")`? The split function does not support escaping like this, but you might be able to craft a regular expression that'll work for this case, like with a zero-width negative assertion look behind group: `(?<!\\)\|` which would be `line.split("(?<!\\\\)\\|"); `

Answer (score 6):

You can simply do this:

```
String[] arrayString = yourString.split("\\|");
```

Comment: you have to escape the \ to use you're regex "yourString.split("\\|")" that's the right formula.