# Hadoop - Pipe delimiter not recognized

Tags: java, parsing, hadoop

I want to split a file with a pipe character on a string like `number|twitter|abc..` in the mapper.
It is a long string. But it doesn't recognize pipe delimiter when I do:

```
String[] columnArray = line.split("|");
```

If I try to split it with a space like `line.split(" ")`, it works fine so I don't think there is a problem with it recognizing characters.
 Is there any other character that can look like pipe? Why doesn't split recognize the `|` character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shared in another answer
"String.split expects a regular expression argument. An unescaped | is parsed as a regex meaning "empty string or empty string," which isn't what you mean."
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9808719/2623158

Here's a test example.

```
public class Test
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String str = "test|pipe|delimeter";
      String [] tmpAr = str.split("\\|");

      for(String s : tmpAr)
      {
         System.out.println(s);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.split` takes a regular expression (as the javadoc states), and `"|"` is a special character in regular expressions.  try `"[|]"` instead.