# Using split() with "|" character

Tags: java, split

Just a quick question:

```
String input = "sam|y|rutgers";
String[] splitInput = input.split("|");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitInput));

Output:
[, s, a, m, |, y, |, r, u, t, g, e, r, s]
```

I would like to split at the pipe characters to get 
[sam,y,rutgers]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: "|" is a special regex character. Use `String[] splitInput = input.split("\\|");`

Comment: Please read the javadoc of methods you use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808689/why-does-string-split-need-pipe-delimiter-to-be-escaped

Comment: So many upvotes for a question that doesn't deserve it.

Comment: @user2812890: You could accept the answers people give you

Answer (score 8):

Try with one of these

- `split("\\|")`
- `split("[|]")`
- `split(Pattern.quote("|"))`
- `split("\\Q|\\E")`

`split` method uses regex as parameter and in regex `|` means OR so your current expression means *empty string* or *empty String*.

If you want to make `|` simple literal you need to escape it. To do this you can

- place `\` before it in regex engine which in String will be written as `"\\|"`.
- use character class `[...]` to escape most of regex metacharacters like `split("[|]")`
- or surround your special characters with `\\Q` and `\\E` which will make every character (regardless if it is special or not) simple literal. This solution is used in `Pattern.quote("regex")`.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
String[] str= input.split("\\|");
```

`"|"` is a special character(OR) so you need to escape that using a `slash \\`. As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808689/why-does-string-split-need-pipe-delimiter-to-be-escaped) **An unescaped | is parsed as a regex meaning "empty string or empty string,"**

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by `StringTokenizer`

```
StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(input , "|");

    while (st2.hasMoreElements()) {
        System.out.println(st2.nextElement());
    }
```

default delimeter is `" "` space.

```
StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(input );//it will split you String by `" "` space
```

Answer (score 1):

\Q & \E are regex quotes.

```
String[] splitInput = input.split("\\Q|\\E");
```