# String.Split - Unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, string

I am trying to split a string as follows

```
String string = "mike|ricki"
```

If I do the following `string.split("|")` I would expect an array of 2 elements, `"mike"` and `"ricki"`. Instead I am getting the following

`[, m, i, k, e, |, r, i, c, k, i]`

Am i doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Comment: Related [Using split() with “|” character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20409916/using-split-with-character)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Pipe character `|`  is a special character in regular expressions. You must escape it by using `\`. The escape string would be `\|`, but in Java the backslash `\` is a special character for escape in literal Strings, so you have to double escape it and use `\\|`:

```
String[] names = string.split("\\|");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you read the [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) Java Documentation, it says that it can receive a Regular Expression as an input.

The Pipe character `|` is a special character in regular expressions so if you want to use it as a literal you have to escape it like `\\|`

So your code have to be:

```
String[] splitted = string.split("\\|");
```

**EDIT :** Corrected sample code.

Comment: -1: Your answer was right until you added that very odd line of code at the end of your answer =\. You need to escape the regular expression, not the String where you will apply the regex.

Comment: You don't need the original string to change, just the regex you're matching in the split

Comment: Ups! I will corect it.

Answer (score 0):

String.split takes a regular expression.  The pipe character has a special meaning in regex so it's not matching as you were expecting.

Try `String.split("\\|")` instead.

The backslash tells regex to treat the pipe as a literal character.