# | not recognized in java string.split() method

Tags: java, string

I am having problems with the java string.split method.

I have a string word like so, which equals- `freshness|originality`. I then split this string like so:

```
   String words[] = word.split("|");
```

If I then output words[1], like so:

```
    t1.setText(words[1]);
```

It gives me the value f. I have worked out that this is the f in the word `freshness`.

How can I split the string properly so that words[1] is actually `originality`? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should escape it:

```
String words[] = word.split("\\|");
```

Check this explanation in similar question here: [Why does String.split need pipe delimiter to be escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808689/why-does-string-split-need-pipe-delimiter-to-be-escaped)

String object's `split()` method has a regular expression as a parameter. That means an unescaped `|` is not interpreted as a character but as OR and means "empty string OR empty string".

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the pipe because java recognizes it as a Regular Expression OR Operator.

```
line.split("\\|")
```

`"|"` gets is parsed as "empty string or empty string," which isn't what you are trying to find.

For the record

... ? . + ^ : - $ *

are all Regex Operators and need to be escaped.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the character. Use `"\\|"`.

More information on regex escaped characters [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134558/java-regex-list-of-all-special-characters-that-needs-to-be-escaped-in-regex).

Comment: It gives me the error saying that it is an invalid escape sequence

Comment: @James Yeah, I forgot to double the backslash. it should be good now.

Comment: Sorry it does work after all!

Answer (score 0):

```
        String test ="freshness|originality";
        String[] splits = test.split("\\|");
        String part1 = splits[0]; // freshness
        String part2 = splits[1]; // originality
```