# Why does "0".split("|") return two elements instead of one?

Tags: java, split

Java string split: If I split "0" with delimiter "|" I expect array of one element as in ["0"]. But what I actually get is {"","0"}

How to fix this? Thanks

Comment: You need to escape `|`

Comment: Hi, I do not agree this is a duplicate, because people might not realize it's pipe symbol that's causing it until they see this question.

Answer (score 0):

Argument to string split is a regex not a string. So pipeline symbol does not mean pipeline symbol. [Why does String.split need pipe delimiter to be escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808689/why-does-string-split-need-pipe-delimiter-to-be-escaped)

Using "\\|" worked