# Why I cannot split string with $ in Java

Tags: java, split

I was just doodling on `eclipse IDE` and written following code.

```
String str = new String("A$B$C$D");
String arrStr[] = str.split("$");
for (int i = 0; i < arrStr.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Val: "+arrStr[i]);
}
```

I was expecting output like:
Val: A
Val: B
Val: C
Val: D
But instead of this, I got output as

`Val: A$B$C$D`
Why? I am thinking may be its internally treated as a special input or may be its like variable declaration rules.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does String.split need pipe delimiter to be escaped?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808689/why-does-string-split-need-pipe-delimiter-to-be-escaped)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The method `String.split(String regex)` takes a regular expression as parameter so `$` means EOL.

If you want to split by the character `$` you can use

```
String arrStr[] = str.split(Pattern.quote("$"));
```

Comment: A little overhead for escaping the dollar symbol ;)

Comment: You don't have to think about how to escape any character => less error prone.

Comment: But split method will work if I use different characters like "_" or ",".

Comment: @Avinash: "_" and "," are no special regexp characters. They are treated as they are. Please read the javadoc for regular expressions: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 8):

You have to escape "$":

```
arrStr = str.split("\\$");
```

Answer (score 4):

You have used `$` as regex for split. That character is already defined in regular expression for "The end of a line" ([refer this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)). So you need to escape the character from actual regular expression and your splitting character should be `$`.

So use `str.split("\\$")` instead of `str.split("$")` in your code

Answer (score 3):

The `split()` method accepts a string that resembles a regular expression (see [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))). In regular expressions, the `$` char is reserved (matching "the end of the line", see [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum)). Therefore you have to escape it as Avinash wrote.

```
String arrStr[] = str.split("\\$");
```

The double-backslash is to escape the backslash itself.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple. The "$" character is reserved that means you need to escape it.

```
String str = new String("A$B$C$D");
String arrStr[] = str.split("\\$");
for (int i = 0; i < arrStr.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Val: "+arrStr[i]);
}
```

That should work fine. So whenever something like this happens escape the character!