# Apache Spark RDD and Java 8: Exception handling

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-8

I need to skip the record, if i get any exception while iterating the file content using Java 8 and Spark.

I do not want to throw exception, i just need to skip that record and continue with other records.

Code Example is :

```
JavaRDD<Model> fileRDD = sc.textFile("filePath")
                .map(line -> {
                    try {
                    String[] parts = line.split("\\|");
                    Long key = Long.parseLong(parts[0];
                    return line;
                    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                        //if i throw RuntimeException, its working file
                        //but i dont want to throw exception, i want to just skip the line,
                        // how do i do it using java 8 stream methods
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.html#filter%28org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function%29) instead of `map`:

```
JavaRDD<Model> fileRDD = sc.textFile("filePath")
            .filter(line -> {
                try {
                    String[] parts = line.split("\\|");
                    Long key = Long.parseLong(parts[0];
                    return true;
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: inside map i have to do lot of other works, so before doing map i need to filter then start process the records using map.

Comment: @Shankar, sure, you can first `filter`, then `map`.

Answer (score 1):

`String[] parts = line.split("|");`

The pipe character should be escaped.

`String[] parts = line.split("\\|");`

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9808719/3662739

Comment: actually i have escaped the pipe character..anyway thanks for that.

Comment: oh, nvm then xD, I thought that would make the array break and that's why you couldn't skip.

Comment: While this is a reasonable comment to the question, it's a *comment*, not an answer. Please avoid posting comments as answers. When you'll earn reputation 50, you will be able to post comments as well.