# Java Delimiter printing characters individually

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am new to java and i am trying to create a simple program which would parse  a string using delimiter. However whenever i try do this instead of printing the lines like this:

```
Hello World 
I am Bob 
how are you
```

it prints out each character individually on its own line. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]){ 
        String s = "Hello World|I am bob|how are you ";
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(s);
        scan.useDelimiter("|");
        System.out.println(scan.next());
        while (scan.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(scan.next());
        }

    }
}
```

Any help would be apreciated

Comment: `|` (pipeline) has a special meaning in regular expressions - you need to escape it. Read this very close topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808689/why-does-string-split-need-pipe-delimiter-to-be-escaped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pm 77-1 has stated you have to escape the pipe character:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ScannerDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String s = "Hello World|I am bob|how are you ";
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(s);
        scan.useDelimiter("\\|");
        System.out.println(scan.next());
        while (scan.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(scan.next());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use different delimiter as PIPE has special character which needs to escaped.

If strictly need PIPE symbol then try

```
scan.useDelimiter("\\|");
```

Comment: Just to add... I really dont know the purpose of your requirement. But if you just want to delimit only from String (not any other IO operation) then i would suggest you to use the split method in String class which will return String array.